# Representation of probability measure over product spaces

Tags: convexity, probability-distributions

Trying to obtain some exchangeability-related results, I ended up with the following questions, which I couldn't answer (at least, not in the negative); this is also related to this [MO thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/152907/convex-hulls-of-families-of-probability-measures) (edit: actually, not really)

Given a measurable space $(S,\mathscr{S})$, let $\pi$ be a probability measure on the product space $(S^2,\mathscr{S}^2)$. Also, endow the set $\mathcal{P}(S)$ of probability measures over $(S,\mathscr{S})$ with the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the measurable maps $\nu \mapsto \nu(F)$, with $F \in \mathscr{S}$ (and similarly for $\mathcal{P}(S)^2$).

> **Question.** Is it true that we can find *always* a probability measure $\mu$ on $\mathcal{P}(S)^2$ such that
>   $$
> \pi(A)=\int_{\mathcal{P}(S)^2} (\alpha \otimes \beta)(A) \,\mu(\mathrm{d}(\alpha\otimes \beta))\,\,\,\,\,?
> $$
>   for all $A \in \mathscr{S}^2$.

[Here, given probability measures $\alpha,\beta$ on $(S,\mathscr{S})$, we let $\alpha \otimes \beta$ denote their product measure]

Comment: You're trying to integrate a function whose codomain is $\mathcal{P}(S^2)$ - can you explain how this is to be interepreted?  Most "vector-valued" integrals (Bochner, Pettis, etc) tend to need a codomain which is a Banach space, or at least some sort of "complete" topological vector space.  Here we do not have a vector space (though it does have a convex structure), and you have not specified a topology.

Comment: Or do you simply want $\pi(A) = \int_{\mathcal{P}(S^2)} (\alpha \otimes \beta)(A) \mu(d\alpha, d\beta)$ for all measurable sets $A$?

Comment: I mean the second one, for all $A \in \mathscr{S}^2$; sorry for having been not clear, I add it in the text..

Comment: And you meant $\mu$ to be a probability measure on $\mathcal{P}(S^2)$?

Comment: So it seems an obvious thing to do is to consider the map $S^2 \to \mathcal{P}(S^2)$ that sends $(x,y)$ to the Dirac mass $\delta_{(x,y)}$, and try letting $\mu$ be the pushforward of $\pi$ under this map.  There are some measurability things to check, though.

Comment: Actually, I am still confused by the notation: the $\mu(d\alpha, d\beta)$ notation makes it look like $\mu$ is meant to be a measure not on $\mathcal{P}(S^2)$ but on $(\mathcal{P}(S))^2$.  Though it seems to me that the idea I mentioned above works in either case, since the measure $\mu$ would be supported on the subset of $\mathcal{P}(S^2)$ which consists of product measures (indeed, products of point masses).

Comment: Not sure if your latest edit was in response to my comment, but it doesn't resolve my question.  If $\mu$ has support on a set of measures $\gamma$ which are not product measures, then $\alpha \otimes \beta$ doesn't strictly speaking make sense, since $\gamma$ cannot be factored into $\alpha \otimes \beta$.  It seems like maybe you simply want $\int \gamma(A) \,\mu(d\gamma)$?  And having checked some details, it seems to me that the "Dirac mass" idea works fine - should I post it, or would you like to explain where you encountered trouble?

Comment: You were correct, especially about the notation. I didn't realize that at the end it was just a change of variables, my bad. Thank you Nate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true; we can use the following rather trivial construction.

Notation: for measurable $A \subset S^2$, let $F_A : \mathcal{P}(S)^2 \to [0,1]$ be the "evaluation map" $F_A(\alpha, \beta) = (\alpha \otimes \beta)(A)$.

Consider the map $T : S^2 \to \mathcal{P}(S)^2$ defined by $T(x,y) = (\delta_x, \delta_y)$.  This is the natural way to embed a space into its space of probability measures: map a point to a point mass.  We note that $T$ is measurable, since for any $F_A$ we have $F_A(T(x,y)) = (\delta_x \otimes \delta_y)(A) = 1_A(x,y)$.  So $F_A \circ T = 1_A$ is a measurable map from $S^2$ to $[0,1]$.  Since the $F_A$ generate the $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathcal{P}(S^2)$, the measurability of $T$ follows.

Now for a given measure $\pi$, simply let $\mu = \pi \circ T^{-1}$ be the pushforward of $\pi$ under $T$. Then by change of variables
$$\begin{align*}\int_{\mathcal{P}(S)^2} F_A(\alpha, \beta) \,\mu(d\alpha, d\beta)  &= \int_{S^2} F_A(T(x,y))\,\pi(dx, dy) \\ &= \int_{S^2} 1_A(x,y)\,\pi(dx,dy) \\ &= \pi(A).\end{align*}$$