# Bochner integral over convex sets lies in the convex set?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, integration

Let $(\Omega,\Sigma,\mu)$ be a probability space, $E$ be a separable Banach space, $f:\Omega\rightarrow E$ be Borel-measurable and consider the Bochner-integral
$$
\bar{\mu}:=\int_{\omega\in \Omega}\, f(\omega)\, \mu(d\omega).
$$
If there is a convex set $C\subseteq E$, such that $f(\Omega)$ is a compact subset of $C$ then, is $\bar{\mu}\in C$?

Comment: Aren't you satisfied with the intergal being in the **closure** of $C$?

Comment: Ah, that's precisely my problem; in my setting, I need it to genuinely lie in C.  The most I can assume is that $f(\Omega)$ is a *compact subset* of $C$ (instead of assuming that it is only contained in $C$; would this be enough?)

Comment: See the notion of "measure-convex set" ... https://mathoverflow.net/a/152951/454

Answer (score 5):

Let $\Omega=\mathbb N=\{1,2,3,\cdots\}$ and $\mu(\{n\}) = 2^{-n}$ with $\Sigma = 2^\Omega$.  Consider $E=c_0$ with $f:\Omega\rightarrow E$ given by $f(n+1) = 2^{-n} e_n$ where $e_n$ is the $n$th standard unit vector basis element, and $f(1)=0$.  Then the image of $f$ is $\{0\} \cup \{ 2^{-n}e_n\}$ which is compact in $c_0$.  The integral is
$$ \int_\Omega f = \sum_n 2^{-n} f(n) = \frac12 \sum_n 4^{-n} e_n \in c_0. $$
If we take $C$ to be the convex hull of $\{0\} \cup \{ 2^{-n} e_n\}$ (no closure!) then $f$ maps into $C$ but the integral of $C$ is only in the closure of $C$, not $C$ itself.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem many years ago (if I remember correctly), and the answer was negative. I think that I had found a counterexample in the monograph of Diestel and Uhl.

If $E$ has finite dimension, the answer is positive, because the convex hull of a compact subset is compact in this case and thus automatically closed.

Comment: I think that this would be a great answer with the counterexample (or a precise reference), but, as is, this is probably more of a comment.

Comment: I do not have the references here, so I cannot provide them. Anyway, Matthew's answer is very similar to the example I have seen at that time.